# Main.cs Missing from Solution Explorer

Tags: c#

[image]

I am a beginner in programming. Up until today my main.cs (frmMain) was in the solution explorer but now it is doesn't show anymore. I can still open it using different methods. Is there a way of adding it back into the solution explorer?

Comment: Right click on your project and select Add => Existing Item

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your solution explorer and of where the file is?

Comment: I put up a screenshot. It used to be under main.cs(design). When I add the exiting item it appears under the solution. How can I add it back to where it was?

Answer (score 2):

Right mouse button on your project and go to Add -> existing item and select your main.cs

Answer (score 2):

solution explorer>> Rightclick project >>> Add>> Existing item >> browse location

Answer (score 1):

Apart from 
`Right mouse button on your project and go to Add -> existing item and select your main.cs`, if the file is exist in where it should be, you can :

1. click **Show All Files**
2. select the item that you want to be included in your project
3. right click the item and click **Include in project**

Hope it can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

drag and drop the file into the solution explorer.